# Where can I download Amd catalyst center version 16.9 or 16.11?

Tags: mining-hardware

This one 
https://forum.ethereum.org/discussion/11159/rx-480-sapphire-nitro-oc-4gb-modded-to-8gb-31-mh-1225-2200-mhz

says that I should download

> Amd catalyst center version 16.9 or 16.11 other versions need to be
>   patched to work with modded bioses as they check for the bios
>   signature and will deactivate the card

The problem is, other versions of what?

What is catalyst center? Is it a driver for AMD radeon or what?

I thought the drivers name is called crimson

Where can I download it because I do not see catalyst center 16.11 anywhere on page mentioned.